# Error creating Setter Getter for atomic property on ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, setter, getter

I am trying to create a setter/getter for a property on ARC.

I have this:

```
@property (strong, atomic) MyMytableArrayClass *myArray;

-(MyMytableArrayClass*) myArray {
  @synchronized(self) {
    if (_myArray == nil) { //*
      _myArray = [[MyMytableArrayClass alloc] init]; //*
      _myArray.flag = YES; //*
      }
    return _myArray; //*
  }
}

-(void) setMyArray:(MyMytableArrayClass*)anArray {
  @synchronized(self) {
    _myArray = anArray; //*
  }
}
```

I have errors on the lines marked with //* with this error **use of undeclared identifier  _myArray** why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler *only* automatically synthesizes the instance variable for a property
if it has to synthesize at *least one accessor method*.

If you implement both setter and getter method for your property (or if you implement
the getter for a read-only property), the instance variable is *not* synthesized
automatically.

In this case you have to add

```
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;
```

explicitly if you need the instance variable. Alternatively, you can declare
`_myArray` as an ivar in the class extension.

Comment: I realized that a fraction of time before your answer, but anyway you have confirmed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

> The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will assume that you are taking control over the property implementation and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.
>
> If you still need an instance variable, you’ll need to request that one be synthesized:
>
> ```
> @synthesize property = _property;
> ```